# jquery and page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code in my asp.net webform, I call a webmethod to load data from database:

```
function Inicializar() {
   $("#wait").show();

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "index.aspx/Iniciar",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            $("#wait").hide();

            var result = response.d;
            cargardatos(result );
        }
    });

}
```

I call this function in ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 Inicializar();
});
```

the first time it works, the problem is that when I press F5 and reload the page data is not loaded, and if I press back working again.

I do not know if I'm doing something wrong.

Sorry for my English..Xd

Thank you. Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is **CaSe SenSitIve**. So change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   Inicializar();
});
```

But this way, it doesn't even work on the first time. And do check what is wrong with your output using the Network or Console.

**Disable Caching if Needed**

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url      : "index.aspx/Iniciar",
    cache    : false,
    datatype : 'json'
})
```

Comment: Hello, the first time works and it's what I do not understand, in my webform I wrote it correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be a cache issue then. Disable caching, by giving an option `cache: false` in the `$.ajax()` function.

Comment: Hi, it worked, but if I press the f5 key followed many times, do not ever load the data, but I do not think any user do that .. Xdd

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off caching

```
function Inicializar() {
   $("#wait").show();

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url      : "index.aspx/Iniciar",
        cache    : false,
        datatype : 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {
        $("#wait").hide();
        cargardatos(response.d);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    Inicializar();
});
```